# Count how many text files in a directory using python 2.7 and edit them

Tags: python, python-2.7, variables, counting

I need help with counting the amount of files in a directory/folder (Windows 7) in python so then if there is more than 20 .txt files I can delete some there is always 20 files that are .txt. If you create another one, using python, it deletes the oldest one.

Any answers will be helpful, thank you.

```
import os
(_, _, my_files) = os.walk("C:\\Users\\guest.user\\task2").next()
amount = len([f for f in my_files if f.endswith('.txt')])

print amount

if amount > 20:
#This is my next problem - needs to truncate the file once there is more than 20
```

Comment: Can you paste some code what you've tried so far?

Comment: Why use os.walk when you're clearly not interested in subdirectories? os.listdir gives you all files in one directory. And glob.glob even lets you specify a pattern, like glob.glob('*.txt').

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Count the txt files**

```
import os


(_, _, my_files) = os.walk('some_directory').next()
print len([f for f in my_files if f.endswith('.txt')])
```

**Count the txt files and delete the ones that're beyond the first 10**

```
import os


(_, _, my_files) = os.walk('some_directory').next()
if len([f for f in my_files if f.endswith('.txt')]) > 10:
    for f in my_files[9:]:
        os.remove(os.path.join('some_directory', f))
```

**Count the txt files and delete anything after x-number of files**

```
import os


my_directory = 'some_directory'
max_files = 20

(_, _, my_files) = os.walk(my_directory).next()

if len([f for f in my_files if f.endswith('.txt')]) > max_files:
    for f in my_files[max_files-1:]:
        os.remove(os.path.join(my_directory, f))
```

Comment: Can you do it so if I have 21 files it will delete 1?

Comment: @SirLuca Yeah, let me know if the code I just added works (the last code).

Comment: I gives me this error: NameError: name 'max_files' is not defined @Mr_Spock

Comment: Don't worry - fixed it, Thank you

Comment: @SirLuca Was it an error in my code? If so, please let me know so I can fix it. This is a public forum, so others might need the same help! The answer should be correct. :-)

Comment: Yes, "max_files" wasn't defined but I defined it.

Comment: @SirLuca It's defined on line 5.

Comment: HOWEVER, it removes ALL the .txt files, I just want it to remove the oldest .txt file when the count of the .txt files has reached >20

Comment: @SirLuca Then, I didn't understand your question. So you want to keep all of the files except for the oldest file if the file count is above 20?

Answer (score 1):

For the size, use the following:

```
import os

filesInDir = os.listdir(myPath) # returns a list with all the file names in that directory
numOfFilesInDir = len(filesInDir)
```

To delete a file, use the following:

```
import os

os.delete(pathToFile)
```

To check the time of the creation of the file:

```
import os

(mode, ino, dev, nlink, uid, gid, size, atime, mtime, ctime) = os.stat(pathToFile)
# ctime is the creation time of the file.
```

To create a file:

```
open(filePath, 'w')
```